# CakePHP 4.1 saving belongsTo association doesn't work

Tags: cakephp, orm, entity, cakephp-4.x

I have two DB tables - `Users` and `UserTypes` where `Users` has a foreign key `user_type_id`.
Below is their boilerplate model code.

`Entity/User.php`:

```
class User extends Entity {
    protected $_accessible = [
        'id' => true,
        'email' => true,
        'password' => true,
        'name' => true,
        'user_type_id' => true, // added this as an experiment now, but I shouldn't need it if I understand correctly
        'user_type' => true
    ];
}
```

`Entity/UserType.php`:

```
class UserType extends Entity {
    protected $_accessible = [
        'id' => true,
        'name' => true,
        'users' => true,
    ];
}
```

`Table/UsersTable.php`:

```
class UsersTable extends Table
{
public function initialize(array $config): void
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->setTable('users');
    $this->setDisplayField('name');
    $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

    $this->belongsTo('UserTypes', [
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
}


public function validationDefault(Validator $validator): Validator
{
    $validator
        ->integer('id')
        ->allowEmptyString('id', null, 'create');

    $validator
        ->email('email')
        ->requirePresence('email', 'create')
        ->notEmptyString('email');

    $validator
        ->scalar('password')
        ->maxLength('password', 255)
        ->requirePresence('password', 'create')
        ->notEmptyString('password');

    $validator
        ->scalar('name')
        ->maxLength('name', 255)
        ->allowEmptyString('name');

    return $validator;
}

public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules): RulesChecker
{
    $rules->add($rules->isUnique(['email']));
    $rules->add($rules->existsIn(['user_type_id'], 'UserTypes'));

    return $rules;
}
}
```

`Table/UserTypesTable.php`:

```
class UserTypesTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config): void
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('user_types');
        $this->setDisplayField('name');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');
        $this->hasMany('Users');
    }

    public function validationDefault(Validator $validator): Validator
    {
        $validator
            ->integer('id')
            ->allowEmptyString('id', null, 'create');

        $validator
            ->scalar('name')
            ->requirePresence('name', 'create')
            ->notEmptyString('name');

        return $validator;
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that I don't seem to be able to save the `user_type_id` field of a record in the `users` table of the database.
To reproduce the issue, I have created a the following simple action in `UsersController.php`:

```
public function testAdd()
{
    $testUser = $this->Users->newEmptyEntity();
    $testUser->name = "Test";
    $testUser->email = "test@test.com";
    $testUser->password = "secret";
    $testUser->user_type = $this->Users->UserTypes->get(1); // this exists and I've verified get() finds it correctly
    $this->Users->save($testUser);
}
```

The result of this is `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails` and the attempted query is `INSERT INTO users (email, password, name) VALUES (:c0, :c1, :c2)` which clearly doesn't have the necessary `user_type_id` field.

I have tried changing an existing user's user type which doesn't fail (since the FK constraint is already satisfied) but no change occurs either.

I have also tried `$this->Users->save($testUser, ['associated' => ['UserTypes']]);` which changed nothing for the resulting `INSERT` SQL query.

So my question is, how can I insert and update the foreign key field of my User entity?

---- EDIT ----

Running `debug(get_class($this->Users))` just before `save()` yields:

```
APP/Controller/UsersController.php (line 270)
'App\Model\Table\UsersTable'
```

And running `debug($testUser)` just before `save()` yields:

```
APP/Controller/UsersController.php (line 271)
object(App\Model\Entity\User) id:0 {
'name' => 'Test'
'email' => 'test@test.com'
'password' => '$2y$10$13nmS6Iag3seqkae9L.M0Ow.xV0Tasd/y9XNu12xX9yIozsXNLEnO'
'user_type' => object(App\Model\Entity\UserType) id:1 {
'id' => (int) 1
'name' => 'Full admin'
'[new]' => false
'[accessible]' => [
'id' => true,
'name' => true,
'users' => true,
]
'[dirty]' => [
]
'[original]' => [
]
'[virtual]' => [
]
'[hasErrors]' => false
'[errors]' => [
]
'[invalid]' => [
]
'[repository]' => 'UserTypes'
protected _accessible => [
'id' => true,
'name' => true,
'users' => true,
]
protected _fields => [
'id' => (int) 1,
'name' => 'Full admin',
]
protected _original => [
]
protected _hidden => [
]
protected _virtual => [
]
protected _dirty => [
]
protected _accessors => [
'App\Model\Entity\User' => [
'set' => [
'password' => '_setPassword',
'Password' => '_setPassword',
'name' => '',
'email' => '',
'user_type' => '',
],
],
]
protected _new => false
protected _errors => [
]
protected _invalid => [
]
protected _registryAlias => 'UserTypes'
}
'[new]' => true
'[accessible]' => [
'id' => true,
'email' => true,
'password' => true,
'name' => true,
'created' => true,
'modified' => true,
'user_type_id' => true,
'user_type' => true
]
'[dirty]' => [
'name' => true,
'email' => true,
'password' => true,
'user_type' => true,
]
'[original]' => [
]
'[virtual]' => [
]
'[hasErrors]' => false
'[errors]' => [
]
'[invalid]' => [
]
'[repository]' => 'Users'
protected _accessible => [
'id' => true,
'email' => true,
'password' => true,
'name' => true,
'created' => true,
'modified' => true,
'user_type_id' => true,
'user_type' => true
]
protected _hidden => [
(int) 0 => 'password',
]
protected _fields => [
'name' => 'Test',
'email' => 'test@test.com',
'password' => '$2y$10$13nmS6Iag3seqkau9L.M0Ow.xV0Tasd/y9XNe12xX9yIozsXNLEnO',
'user_type' => object(App\Model\Entity\UserType) id: 1 {},
]
protected _original => [
]
protected _virtual => [
]
protected _dirty => [
'name' => true,
'email' => true,
'password' => true,
'user_type' => true,
]
protected _accessors => [
'App\Model\Entity\User' => [
'set' => [
'password' => '_setPassword',
'Password' => '_setPassword',
'name' => '',
'email' => '',
'user_type' => '',
],
],
]
protected _new => true
protected _errors => [
]
protected _invalid => [
]
protected _registryAlias => 'Users'
}
```

Comment: There's other, simpler ways to do it, but this should work too, so it might be worth figuring out what's happening. Try to gather some context with `debug(get_class($this->Users));` and `debug($testUser);` (right before the `save()` call).

Comment: @ndm I've edited the question to include the two `debug()` outputs. I would also be interested to hear about these simpler ways that you are referring to. Thanks!

Comment: Oh boy, the new debug format doesn't produce real whitespace indentation ;( Anyhow, is `user_type_id` possibly a field that you have added afterwards, ie after the database table had already been created?

Comment: Yep, I was thinking the same about debug :( It was added later, yes. But how would that be relevant if it's properly described in the entity and table objects? Ugh I've always had a bone to pick with ORM

Comment: It's relevant because the ORM will only try to save those fields that are present in the schema, and the schemas are by default being cached, so if you've added a field later on and didn't clear the cache after doing so, your new field won't be saved. Try to clear the model cache (`/tmp/cache/models`) and try again.

Comment: Unbelievable, this was precisely the cause. Thank you! I would still like to hear about the simpler ways you mentioned initially if possible though, in case I'm going through unnecessary hoops.

Comment: Well, the most simple way would be to just populate the foreign key field, ie set `user_type_id` to `1` and you're done.

Comment: Ah yes, makes sense. I had tried that as a supposedly fool-prove operation which, however, also failed because of the outdated schema cache. Not sure what the best stackoverflow practice is to accept your answer since it was in a comment, so I'll just mark it as useful.

Comment: Well, ideally someone would post an answer that can be accepted... I'm rather lazy these days, the heat really crushed me, so your chances for beating me to it are pretty high ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing @ndm's comment as an answer for the sake of anyone who ends up here with the same problem. Turns out my ORM schema was cached before I added the `user_types` DB table. Clearing `/tmp/cache/models` worked for me. Beware the cache!